# How to update Xcode Command Line Tools?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

I am trying to update Command line tools on my mac osx.

```
~  softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   
   * Command Line Tools (macOS El Capitan version 10.11) for Xcode-8.2
    Command Line Tools (macOS El Capitan version 10.11) for Xcode (8.2), 150374K [recommended]
   * iTunesX-12.5.5
    iTunes (12.5.5), 263476K [recommended]
```

But when I run the update command, I get this error:

```
softwareupdate -i Command Line Tools (macOS El Capitan version 10.11) for Xcode-8.2
zsh: number expected
```

This doesn't work either:

```
softwareupdate -i Command Line Tools
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.

Command: No such update
Line: No such update
Tools: No such update
No updates are available.
```

What specific string should I specify after `sofwareupdate -i` command?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For future travelers, here's a version-agnostic approach.  First, run `softwareupdate --list`. This will probably take a couple of minutes. When it's done, you'll see a bulleted (with an asterisk) output like this:

```
$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-10.1
        Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode (10.1), 190584K [recommended]
```

Find the bullet that refers to the Xcode command line tools. Copy that entire line (except the asterisk...). In the above case, you would copy:

> `Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-10.1`

Then, run the *install* command (as shown by Brendan Shanks) with what you copied inside quotes:

```
softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-10.1"
```

Comment: This is the correct suggestion, as it allows you to do this on future releases.

Comment: It fails on Catalina with Xcode 11.3 installed. Run with or without `sudo`, the command returns, "`No new software available.`" But CLT is not intalled. `gcc` and `make` fail to find `xcrun`.

Comment: The problem apprears to be thatI have both Xcode 10.1 and 11.3 installed. As suggested below, running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode11.3.app
` (using the path to my 11.3 version) cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 36):

I'm going to answer a slightly different question here, because this question came up when I searched for a solution to my problem. Hopefully it'll help someone (and it'll surely help me next time I run into the same issue).

I wanted to upgrade the command line tools from version 8 to 9. The App Store didn't suggest this upgrade, and neither did `softwareupdate --list`.

```
xcode-select --install
```

installed the new version of the tools. But `clang --version` still gave 8.0.0 as the version number. `xcode-select -r` and rebooting didn't solve this issue.

`xcode-select -p` returned `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, and `clang --version` reported an installation directory under there. I thought I'd start over again.

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app
```

deleted version 8 of the tools. But `xcode-select --install` said the command line tools were already installed.

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Now, `sudo xcode-select -p` returns `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`.

It seems that the problem was that the new version of the tools are installed to a different directory, and `xcode-select -r` is not clever enough to find the latest version.

Comment: I have no idea how I got into this situation, but I had the same problem, and this resolved it!

Answer (score 10):

Run `softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools (macOS El Capitan version 10.11) for Xcode-8.2"`. The quotes are important.

Comment: Thanks, running the above command with `sudo` keyword did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

The answer given by `brew` (when using an old version of Command Line Tools):

> Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
> `softwareupdate --all --install --force`
>
> If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
>
> `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
>
> `sudo xcode-select --install`

It worked for me, while `softwareupdate --list` did not show anything and `softwareupdate --all --install --force` answered `No updates are available.`.

Answer (score 8):

I faced similar problem on ***MacOS Mojave version 10.14.3*** with ***Xcode 10.3*** installed.
The real problem was, when I installed the *Xcode 10.3*, I deleted the "***Xcode-beta.app***" first and then installed the new version. Therefore, when I tried installing CLion for C++ development and configuring it, ***CMake*** gave me error And Updating Command Line Tool didnt work for me:

```
softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools (macOS Mojave version 10.14.3) for Xcode-10.3"
```

and showed me this response in terminal

```
Software Update Tool
Command Line Tools (macOS Mojave version 10.14.3) for Xcode-10.3: No such update
No updates are available.
```

Then I tried to check the version of Clang using:

```
clang --version
```

And the response lead me to the real problem i.e. Active Developer path was still pointing to Old version of Xcode that I had already deleted.

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
```

Therefore, I switched the active developer path to latest Xcode App installed using:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

And everything worked like a charm automatically.

Comment: This got me out of trouble when I discovered that I was running an old version of Swift, but I had the latest XCode.

Comment: Thank you! I have both Xcode 10.1 and 11.3 installed and running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode11.3.app
` (using the path to my 11.3 version) cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 4):

when upgrading to MacOS Catalina, Version 10.15.* you can install the command line tools for xcode 11.3 like this:

```
$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-11.3
    Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 11.3, Size: 224878K, Recommended: YES,
$ sudo softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools for Xcode-11.3"
```

Answer (score 3):

If `softwareupdate` is not seeing any available CLI tool updates, you can do the following to trick `softwareupdate` into showing everything it has regarding CLI tools.

```bash
# Trick softwareupdate into giving us everything it knows about Xcode CLI tools by
# touching the following file to /tmp
xclt_tmp="/tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress"
/usr/bin/touch "${xclt_tmp}"

# run softwareupdate --list --all again to see if there is anything for CLI tools
softwareupdate --list --all
```

After running the above, you should see something like the below if there are any updates available for the Xcode CLI tools.

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-14.0
        Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 14.0, Size: 687109KiB, Recommended: YES, 
* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-14.2
        Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 14.2, Size: 687573KiB, Recommended: YES,
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran the same command with `sudo` and that did the trick.

`sudo softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools (macOS El Capitan version 10.11) for Xcode-8.2"`

Answer (score 2):

Update everything with

```bash
softwareupdate -i -a
```