# How to update the lldb in macosx

Tags: macos, lldb

My mac is 10.13.4 Beta and the version of the lldb is "lldb-902.0.79.7 switf-4.1".I want to update the lldb but I didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The LLDB binary in `/usr/bin/lldb` searches for the LLDB executable inside the Xcode.app bundle using `xcode-select` internally.

To change which Xcode Application bundle (therefore version) is being used, run `sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/an/Xcode.app`.

For example:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode9.4.app
```

---

**EDIT:**

If any stumbles across this question, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538362/3374794)

Comment: I don't use xcode and I just use the command line version how can I update the lldb