# Homebrew doesn't work after update on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: homebrew

After `homebrew` upgrade, I got Error: `Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.`

My macOS version: `Big Sur 11.0.1`

My Xcode version: `12.4`

And I don't want to upgrade my macOS, so I can't install new version Xcode, how can I use homebrew successful in my Mac？Or myabe revert `homebrew` to the previous version?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538171/how-to-update-xcode-command-line-tools

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried to `brew update-reset`?

P.S. You must be more specific, write more details and what you tried to do to fix. [Please read that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to upgrade your macOS in order to upgrade `xcode`?

For those who can and reached this thread - please follow the list of steps below (taken from [here](https://coady.tech/macos-command-line-tools-outdated/)).

#### Cause

There are many ways this issue could arise (far too many to list here). 
Some of the key suspects are:

(1) Command Line Tools for Xcode not being installed 
(2) A recent Mac OS upgrade 
(3) Firewall app (LuLu) blocking update attempts

#### Hot to fix

First, temporarily disable any 3rd part firewall apps like LuLu or Little Snitch.

Then open Terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools 
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Once complete perform a Homebrew update:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```